# SQL - Difference between current and previous income

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the differnce between current and previous income per customer&date.

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       Date,
       Income
       ,Income - LAG(Income, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Date desc) as diff_from_previous_income
   FROM a
order by CustomerID
```

and I get:

| CustomerID | Date | Income | diff_from_previous_income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/2/2016 | 300 | null |
| 1 | 1/1/2015 | 300 | 0 |
| 2 | 1/3/2016 | 500 | null |
| 3 | 1/4/2016 | 400 | null |
| 4 | 1/5/2015 | 300 | null |
| 4 | 1/12/2016 | 1200 | 900 |

And I don't understand why for CustomerID = 4 the difference apperas near the current purchase (which is what I wanted) but for CustomerID = 1 it appears with the previous one (I thought that order by date desc in the partition clause will solve it but it didn't.)

Any advice? :)

(I used this table:

| CustomerID | InvoiceID | ProductID | Date | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234551 | A | 1/1/2015 | 300 |
| 1 | 1234552 | A | 1/2/2016 | 300 |
| 2 | 1234553 | B | 1/3/2016 | 500 |
| 3 | 1234554 | C | 1/4/2016 | 400 |
| 4 | 1234555 | A | 1/5/2015 | 300 |
| 4 | 1234561 | D | 1/12/2016 | 1200 |

```
CREATE TABLE a (
CustomerID INTEGER,
InvoiceID INTEGER,
ProductID varchar(1),
Date DATE,
Income INTEGER);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 1234551, 'A', '1/1/2015', 300);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 1234552, 'A', '1/2/2016', 300);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (2, 1234553, 'B', '1/3/2016', 500);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (3, 1234554, 'C', '1/4/2016', 400);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (4, 1234555, 'A', '1/5/2015', 300);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (4, 1234561, 'D', '1/12/2016', 1200);)
```

Comment: You want to order ascending. Not descending. SQL FIddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e385200ad5e674ba02f08000c00e76ed

Comment: I tried and it still gives me the diff in the wrong row

Comment: The SQL fiddle linked produces the correct result. If it doesn't, what about the result is incorrect?

Comment: For customerID=1 the difference (0) should appear near the lastest income (from 2016) and should be null for the row from 2015 (as it doesn't have a previous value). The code gives me the opposite. For  customerID=4 it somehow appears as I wanted

Comment: In the fiddle I see the correct result: 0 on the 2nd row (the latest income for customerID 1, from 2016) and null on the 1st row (the 2015 income for customerID 1). I'm not sure where you're looking that you see the opposite. Also, please pick a platform, or ask two separate questions, MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are completely different products and will have different solutions as a result.

Comment: Please recheck this fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75c19d0258842ca693114c1aa95562c0

1 2016-01-02 300 0

Comment: ^ fiddle is correct. Maybe you have your monitor sideways or something.

Answer (score 1):

The date order by needs to be ascending. Here is a fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75c19d0258842ca693114c1aa95562c0

Output

> ```
> CustomerID | c_Date     | Income | diff_from_previous_income
> ---------: | :--------- | -----: | ------------------------:
>          1 | 2015-01-01 |    300 |                      null
>          1 | 2016-01-02 |    300 |                         0
>          2 | 2016-01-03 |    500 |                      null
>          3 | 2016-01-04 |    400 |                      null
>          4 | 2015-01-05 |    300 |                      null
>          4 | 2016-01-12 |   1200 |                       900
> ```